# Any difference between "coming up, coming up next, next, up next, ...."

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

On TV channels, I often hear the following expressions used very often to refer to the subjects to be covered later in their show before they take a break for commercials. However, the TV presenters use many different expressions. So, I wonder if there is any difference between the following:

- Also in the program,....
- Also,....
- Coming up....
- Coming up next...
- Next,
- Up next

Do they all mean the same thing, or are there any differences?

Comment: @JohnArvin, you are trying to edit the question in a way that changes it from the what the original post asked. This edit is not an improvement and it will be rejected. If you want information beyond what the original post asked for, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

All of you examples are used by TV presenters to inform the viewer what is in store in the hope they will continue to watch.  The main difference between your examples is that when

> **next**

is used, it usually signals the *very next topic* after the break, otherwise, the topic may occur at any point before the end of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do all mean the same thing and no, there are no diffrences…